# Avoid double quotes when deriving Show on newtype

Tags: haskell, show, newtype

I want to print the internal value of a `newtype` by deriving `Show` in the following way, so that I don't have to unwrap `Value val` every time it needs to be printed.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}

import Data.Text

newtype Value = Value Text
instance Show Value where show (Value val) = show val


main :: IO ()
main = do
    let hello = Value "hello"
        world = Value "world"
    print $ show hello <> ", " <> show world
    pure ()
```

The idea being that I can simply `show hello` instead of doing `let Value helloVal = hello in show helloVal` (a bit of a contrived example but the main point is to avoid unwrapping).

The issue is that this prints the following:

```
"\"hello\", \"world\""
```

Whereas the desired result would be:

```
hello, world
```

How to get to the desired output?

Comment: The “proper” solution is to always use a pretty-printing library such as [`prettyprinter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter) for human-readable output, and always derive `Show`. That way, `Show` can be used for debugging, since it always shows the full value as valid Haskell code which can be entered into GHCi or read back with `Read`. The output of `Show` can be formatted with [`pretty-show`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty-show) for better readability.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I see how that makes sense, however in this context I'm working with a library called `string-interpolate` that works with `Show` (among other things). There's a pretty good explanation of how it works under the hood here: https://williamyaoh.com/posts/2019-05-27-string-interpolation-and-overlapping-instances.html

Comment: @Jivan But `string-interpolate` does exactly what Jon Purdy suggests; it offers its own type class [`Interpolatable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/string-interpolate-0.3.1.0/docs/Data-String-Interpolate-Conversion.html#t:Interpolatable). You should instantiate that with your custom pretty-printer, and keep the compiler-generated default `Show` instance. In fact, the result will be even better this way, because you can produce a `Text` directly and not incur two string-type conversions. (And this class is explicitly discussed at your link...)

Comment: @DanielWagner yep, makes total sense. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general convention of `Show` is that it should produce more or less Haskell code, which, in most simple cases, you could just copy out of GHCi output and plug right back into its input.

This is why `show "foo"` produces a string `"\"foo\""` - with quotes. So that when it's printed in GHCi, you see the quotes. This is also why default derived instance for your type produces `"Value \"foo\""` - that's straight up Haskell code that can be compiled and evaluated to produce the original `Value` value.

But if you really don't want the extra quotes - sure, just convert your `Text` to `String` using `unpack`:

```
instance Show Value where show (Value v) = unpack v
```

Comment: All (current) answers are equally worthy of being accepted — I accepted this one in the end because of the additional explanation on why `show` works how it works (i.e. to produce Haskell code that can be easily copy/pasted)

Answer (score 4):

In the line

```
show (Value val) = show val
```

you use `show` on `val` which is a `Text`. This converts `val` to a `String` performing quoting and escaping. If you don't want that, use `unpack val` instead.

Finally, note that without the proper quoting the output of `show` might be ambiguous when called on, e.g., a list of `Value`. In such case, if the output of `show` is `[a, b, c]` we can't know if the list was of length 3, 2, or 1, since the commas might have been part of the `Text`s inside.

Answer (score 4):

To go from `Text` to `String` without wrapping in quotes, use [`unpack`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:unpack).

```
instance Show Value where
    show (Value val) = unpack val
```

Additionally, note that `print` is equivalent to `putStrLn . show`, so you're effectively calling `show` twice on the value, first on `Value` and second on `String`. If you already have a string, you need to use `putStrLn` rather than `print`.

```
putStrLn $ show hello <> ", " <> show world
```